# x86 Assembly Language - Terminate Program

Tags: x86, assembly

I am sure this is very trivial for most, but I am not very familiar with x86 assembly language. I am just trying to teach myself.

I am in windows. And everywhere I read, I was told to use `INT 21` to return to the operating system. Which this exits the program, but I get an error saying `Unhandled exception at 0x003d1313 in Assignment1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xffffffff`.

Thanks!

Comment: Process is a platform dependent concept. Which platform are you concerned about?

Comment: I've edited the code. Note that x86 != x86_64

Comment: @Johnny Whisman: "int 21" is for DOS

Comment: @Johnny Whisman: modern OS's (including Windows, Linux and Mac) strictly separate "kernel space" from "user space".  User space programs (like Assignment1.exe) are usually NOT allowed to run "privileged commands" (like "int 21").   DOS let you "talk directly to the metal"; Windows doesn't.  'Hope that helps...

Comment: @paulsm4: `int` is not a privileged instruction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Windows, if you are using a formal assembler (e.g. MASM), you can simply call the following:

```
.386 
.model flat, stdcall 
option casemap:none 
include \masm32\include\windows.inc 
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc 
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib 
.data 
.code 
start: 
        invoke ExitProcess,0 
end start
```

If you are not using any assembler and want to simply execute a chunk of binary code, execute the following:

```
push xxx
push -1
push 0
mov eax, yyy
mov edx, 7FFE0300
call dword ptr ds:[edx]
```

where xxx is the exit code of the process and yyy is the system call number for `NtTerminateProcess` ( use http://www.pediy.com/document/Windows_System_Call_Table/Windows_System_Call_Table.htm to determine the call number for appropriate OS. it's 0x172 for Windows 7)

Comment: Note the latter method is rather a hack-ish method. There's no guarantee that it would work for future versions of Windows NT. It's best to just use Kernel32.dll's ExitProcess API if you know the location of it.

Answer (score 4):

The answer depends entirely on what operating system you're using :)

Here's an example using "int 0x80" on Linux:

```
movl $1, %eax
movl $0, %ebx
int $0x80
```

This Wikipedia link gives you more options:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_%28operating_system%29

Answer (score 3):

If your stack is balanced, the easiest way to exit your program is

```
retn
```